# Integer divide by Zero and Float (Real no.) divide by Zero

Tags: math, language-agnostic, divide-by-zero

If I run following line of code, I get `DIVIDE BY ZERO` error

```
1. System.out.println(5/0);
```

which is the expected behavior.

Now I run the below line of code

```
2. System.out.println(5/0F);
```

here there is no `DIVIDE BY ZERO` error, rather it shows `INFINITY`

In the first line I am dividing two integers and in the second two real numbers.

Why does dividing by zero for integers gives `DIVIDE BY ZERO` error while in the case of real numbers it gives `INFINITY`

I am sure it is not specific to any programming language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(EDIT: The question has been changed a bit - it specifically referred to Java at one point.)

The integer types in Java don't *have* representations of infinity, "not a number" values etc - whereas IEEE-754 floating point types such as `float` and `double` do. It's as simple as that, really. It's not really a "real" vs "integer" difference - for example, `BigDecimal` represents real numbers too, but *it* doesn't have a representation of infinity either.

EDIT: Just to be clear, this *is* language/platform specific, in that you could create your own language/platform which worked differently. However, the underlying CPUs typically work the same way - so you'll find that many, many languages behave this way.

EDIT: In terms of *motivation*, bear in mind that for the infinity case in particular, there are ways of getting to infinity *without* dividing by zero - such as dividing by a very, very small floating point number. In the case of integers, there's obviously nothing between zero and one.

Also bear in mind that the cases in which integers (or decimal floating point types) are used typically don't need to concept of infinity, or "not a number" results - whereas in scientific applications (where `float`/`double` are more typically useful), "infinity" (or at least, "a number which is too large to sensibly represent") is still a potentially valid result.

Comment: If we run a similar program in C language the result would be similar. So it has nothing do with Java.

Comment: It has to do with how numbers are represented. Jon is on the money with this as usual. Do you actually have a question? Or are you just trying to understand why it works the way it does?

Comment: @Apurv: It *is* language/platform specific - you could create a language which had integer types which *did* know about infinity. You might have fun optimizing it to work with CPUs which have direct support for the kind of native types we're used to.

Comment: @metalideath I am trying to understand why it works that way.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your help. Has it anything to do with the fact that the integer calculations are done in the processor itself while real number calculations are done in a math co-processor ?

Comment: @Apurv: Not really - basically this is how the integer and floating point representations were designed. They could have been designed in other ways, but these were felt to be the ones most useful for most applications.

Comment: @Apurv At least historically, yes. For integer arithmetic, the CPU registers and corresponding commands sufficed, whereas for floating-point arithmetic you needed that math coprocessor, or floating-point unit (FPU). Of course, nowadays the FPU is integrated into the processor, and CPU registers have reached a width of 64 bit, so would not necessarily need a FPU anymore. However, the FPU also is programmed with algorithms like that for computing the sine, so it makes sense to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

This *is* specific to one programming language or a family of languages. Not all languages allow integers and floats to be used in the same expression. Not all languages have both types (for example, ECMAScript implementations like JavaScript have no notion of an integer type externally). Not all languages have syntax like this to convert values inline.

However, there is an intrinsic difference between **integer arithmetic** and **floating-point arithmetic**. In integer arithmetic, you must *define* that division by zero is an error, because there are no values to represent the result. In floating-point arithmetic, specifically that defined in IEEE-754, there are additional values (combinations of sign bit, exponent and mantissa) for the mathematical concept of infinity and meta-concepts like NaN (not a number).

So we can assume that the `/` operator in this programming language is generic, that it performs integer division if both operands are of the language's integer type; and that it performs floating-point division if at least one of the operands is of a float type of the language, whereas the other operands would be implicitly converted to that float type for the purpose of the operation.

In real-number math, division of a number by a number close to zero is equivalent to multiplying the first number by a number whose absolute is very large (x / (1 / y) = x * y). So it is reasonable that the result of dividing by zero should be (defined as) infinity as the precision of the floating-point value would be exceeded.

Implementation details were to be found in that programming language's specification.